# running 2 different reactJS frontend on google cloud VM, issues accessing port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, npm, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently testing multiple versions of a ReactJS frontend on a Google Cloud VM instance. I successfully set up the first version by changing the "scripts" section in the package.json file to "start": "react-scripts start --host 0.0.0.0". However, I'm encountering issues running the second version.

For the second version, I tried changing the "start" script in package.json to "react-scripts start --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4000" and kept the first version's port as 3000. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

I also ran npm install in the second version's directory, but encountered an error:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/USERNAME/frontendv2reactjs/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 775 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "NAME",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Any help in resolving these issues and running the second version alongside the first on the Google Cloud VM instance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note: JSON does not use a single-quote character for strings. JSON only uses a double-quote character.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? sorry new to this and want to make sure I am understanding :)

Comment: You have a JSON parsing error. Notice the line `npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '`. That is invalid JSON syntax. Strings a delineated by double-quote characters. The error is pointing out a single-quote issue. Example `"version": '1.0.0'` is invalid. `"version": "1.0.0"` is valid.

Comment: it's correct when I open the file, not sure why there is a discrepancy there

Answer (score 1):

From the error message:

```js
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/USERNAME/frontendv2reactjs/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 775 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "NAME",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": '
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

The error appears to be the version identifier in your v2 frontend. it looks like you might have missed a `'` character in the JSON when specifying the version, and/or a comma at the end of that line. take a close look at `/home/USERNAME/frontendv2reactjs/package.json`

Otherwise, from the [react-scripts documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/), consider using the variable PORT instead of the command line argument for some consistency. I can't find anything from running locally that notes `--port` should work. Could be wrong about that, just hard to secure good documentation from their site. Try:

```bash
PORT=4000 react-scripts start --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Is this answer from ChatGPT?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: I don't believe so @JohnHanley. I put it through two chatgpt zero sites. Returned 0% AI.

Comment: @JohnHanley I think I'm flattered that it's clear enough that it appears to be chatgpt, and I know it's probably bad to take from me, but no it isn't.

Comment: @americanflavour - It is getting harder to tell. The reason I wondered is your jump to the unrelated comment regarding PORT, which did not make sense to me (in the scope of the question). Note: some ChatGPT is gibberish. Lots of words that sound good but solve nothing.